# Class type in lambda inside collectors-map-java8

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-stream, collectors

I have a method signature for getting setter method using reflection based on a given getter method of type Method.
Signature of the method is below:

```
Method getSetter(final Method getterMethod, final Class classType)
```

Now from the method for a class I want a map of getter method to associated setter method. My code is below:

```
final Method[] methods = classType.getMethods();
        Stream.of(methods)
                .filter(ReflectionUtils::isGetter)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), (method) -> getSetter(method, classType)));
```

I am getting compilation error at getSetter(method, classType)
It says Wrong first type argument Found:`<lambda parameter>`, required: `java.lang.reflect.Method`

I also tried specifying the type for the lambda parameter. See below

```
Stream.of(methods)
                .filter(ReflectionUtils::isGetter)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), (Method method) -> getSetter(method, classType)));
```

Now it says cannot infer functional interface type.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. https://ideone.com/xt5Fb6 Please can you check your imports, specify exact version of Java and which compiler you are using.

Comment: Hey thanks!! Actually for getSetter method i was throwing NoSuchMethodException I should have made a try catch block instead. I changed. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine with javac 8u25, u40, u60, u71, as well as ecj 3.10.2. The only problem here is raw `Class` parameter which issues a warning. It should be parameterized with `<?>`:

```
Method getSetter(final Method getterMethod, final Class<?> classType) { ... }
```